# Extending Components in rebass.js?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, rebass

Beginner here. As of now I can use `Box` like so:

```
<Box
  p={5}
  fontSize={4}
  width={[ 1, 1, 1/2 ]}
  color='white'
  bg='magenta'>
  Box
</Box>
```

and give it certain specified props, [as it says on the site](https://rebassjs.org/Box):

```
All margin and padding props
width: responsive width
fontSize: responsive font size
color: text color
bg: background color
flex: CSS flex shorthand property
order: CSS order property
alignSelf: CSS align-self property
```

**Question:** What if I need more props?

I know that I can [extend rebass components](https://rebassjs.org/extending), however, this seems to hard-code certain CSS properties into the component. E.g. If my Box is always purple I can create `PurpleBox` and save the color there. Or on their website there is this example:

```
const Container = props =>
  <Box
    {...props}
    mx='auto'
    css={{
      maxWidth: '1024px'
    }}
  />
```

Fair enough!
What what of I need to create a component, say, `PositionedBox` which gets an additional `position` prop for relative **or** absolute positioning?

I would like to use it like so:

```
<Box
  p={5}
  fontSize={4}
  width={[ 1, 1, 1/2 ]}
  color='white'
  bg='magenta'
  position='abs'>
  Box
</Box>
```

Is this possible? Not sure how I could accomplish this.

Answer (score 1):

You could make use of `styled-components` and `styled-system`

```
import styled from "styled-components";
import { position } from "styled-system";

// through interpolation

const StyledBox = styled(Box)`
 // some properties
    ${position}
`;

// passing as a single property
const StyledBox = styled(Box)(position);
```

passing multiple properties

```
import { compose, property1, property2, ... } from "styled-system";

import StyledBox = styled(Box)(compose(property1, property2, ....));
```

this would extend all the position properties supported by the styled system.
list of all the out-of-the-box properties supported by `styled-system` [here](https://styled-system.com/table)